# How to use .NET Identity scaffold users in models

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a model representing a project, a project is supposed to have one or more users attached to it. I have identity scaffolded in my project, and my applicationDB context inherits from the identityDBContext. I want to use the user "model" that comes with the scaffold in one of my own models. How can I accomplish this?

My application db context

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       }

       public DbSet<Project> projects { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Phase> phases { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Models.Task> tasks { get; set; }

   }
```

My project model

```
        public Project()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<???>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<???> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hello Mr.Grease did you tried the solution provided? Do you need any further assistance on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen between the line of your descriptions and code I would suggest following steps for you.

Let's begin with your statement:

> I want to use the user "model" that comes with the scaffold in one of my own models.

Inherit your IdentityUser class in Custom User Class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
    
    {
        public string NewCustomProperty { get; set; }
        public string AnotherCustomProperty { get; set; }

    }
```

**Note:** Remember that we are inheriting this for our implementation flexibility so that our base `IdentityUser` class doesn't get impacted. Therefore, Its not necessary that you have to have property in your derived `User` class.You can make it empty.

Then Inherit your IdentityDbContext class in your ApplicationDbContext:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Project> projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phase> phases { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Models.Task> tasks { get; set; }

}
```

Note: Make sure while you are `Inheriting` `IdentityUser class` make sure you have added the correct `namespace` which is `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

Your Project Model now should be as following:

```cs
 public class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, this worked perfectly. Adding a migration with this set of models clearly adds a table meant to match up projects to users. Thank you

Comment: No problem, glad to assist you.